# How to save the latest state of the data. And will only update itself when new latest state of data appear

Tags: database, node-red

I am now working on a project that uses node-red and mysql. So I have this problem that I am facing, that I have a set of data that keeps on updating. But right now I want to create a new table that just save the latest data(one column of data only) it shows. And only will update when new data is shown.

current table look like this:

```
Power   Current  Voltage  timestamp:
  2w          3A         3v        2:43PM
  3w          4A         4v        2:44PM
```

And the new table I want is:

```
Power   Current  Voltage  timestamp:
  3w          4A         4v        2:44PM
```

The latest data save in the new table. Other will not be shown. And will keep updating itself

Comment: That defeats the point of a database.

Comment: Then may I know how to automatically move the data up like:
Power   Current  Voltage  timestamp:
  2w          3A         3v        2:43PM
  3w          4A         4v        2:44PM
  3w          2A         5v        2:45PM

to:
3w          2A         5v        2:45PM
3w          2A         4v        2:46PM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save the latest data and update the data when a new number show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674125/how-to-save-the-latest-data-and-update-the-data-when-a-new-number-show-up)

Comment: No ah. that's why I want to re-ask the question. How to automatically refresh the data in mysql

Comment: Please do not repost the exact same question that has already been closed. You need to edit the original question in line with the reason it was closed. Reposted questions with no improvement will be closed for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: Can u just tell me the solution for this at here

Comment: The answer is don't use a database, it doesn't do anything useful in the situation you describe